# Validate a request in a view "Orchard"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I just want to validate/detect whether a specific VIEW'S request is through projection-widget or projection page, can anyone help me in this matter ?

Comment: Hmm... sounds like you might be going down an odd path here.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe you can get what you're looking for by implementing separate layouts in the query?

Comment: Basically, I have Projection widget and projection page of the same custom content type list. The problem is, when i try to edit layout/view for projection page, it do the same with widget :( that's why i just want to differentiate the request and handled it accordingly.  Please let me know if there is some better way, I am beginner in orchard.

Comment: I think adding a layout to your query is the answer, but let me know if that's not helping for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a layout to the query?  When you create your project page or widget, you can select the layout that you want to use.  So, just create a layout for your pages to use, and another layout for your widgets to use.  If that's not enough, you could also use Alternates for total control, but it doesn't sound like you really need that.